# When i get NSMutableArray from user Default and trying to replace that object with NSMutableArray i am getting this error

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

> Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' (0x11105e3f8) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x11105d548)

```
let Dict = userDefaults.value(forKey: "(GameID)") as! [String : Any] 
TimeOutDict = HalfSessionDict["timeouts"] as! [String : Any]

print(TimeOutDict) 

if let timOut = TimeOutDict["team_1"] as? NSMutableArray { 
    Team1TimeOutArray = timOut
} 

if let timOut = TimeOutDict["team_2"] as? NSMutableArray { 
    Team2TimeOutArray = timOut 
}
```

Comment: Add your code because i think you are getting `NSArray` from `UserDefaults`

Comment: mutating method sent to immutable object.This explains everything.Just take a minute and learn mutable and immutable in objC.Then check the documentation of user default method you are using.Everything will be cleared :)

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan You mean Swift, not Objective-C.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry i didn't notice the tag.saw the title of question and remembered my old days working withe defaults. Perhaps getting emotional :)

Comment: @Avadh Don't use `NS[Mutable]Array` in Swift. Use Swift arrays.

Comment: @rmaddy i get this error only ios version 11.1 when i run project in ios version 10.3 and lower its run perfect

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you should be using Swift collections, not Objective-C collections. And post the code that actually causes the error.

Answer (score -1):

Saving a NSArray in NSUserDefaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourArray forKey:@"Key"];
```

To get the value as an NSMutableArray:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Key"]];
```

OR

Please use mutableCopy while replacing array object

```
[[_NSCFArray mutableCopy] replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]:
```

Comment: The question is tagged Swift. Answers should be in Swift, not Objective-C.